# C-like languages allowing declarations in any order

Tags: c#, parsing, syntax, compiler-construction

The following C# code is happily accepted, and I believe the same is true in Java, whereas a C++ compiler would barf on the equivalent because Foo is used before being declared:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo;
    }
}

class Foo
{
    int x;
}
```

How does this work in terms of syntax and parsing? Specifically, when the compiler sees the first occurrence of Foo, how does it know to parse it as a declaration instead of something else? Does it go by the juxtaposition of two identifiers, or some other rule?

Comment: Eric Lippert answers this in detail with [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/04/how-many-passes.aspx). Basically C# has a two-pass compiler; the first pass scans for declarations so that the second pass knows what is what.

Comment: @Jon: we really need two pass for this? why can we can't simply generate IL when parsing source code?

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi: Well, you either need two passes or some type of forward declaration of `Foo` and we can rule the latter out because C# isn't specced that way. In addition it would not be possible for the compiler to directly emit IL (which is a different matter entirely) without creating an AST from the source first in any case. An easy proof of that is that if the compiler did not create an AST it would not be possible to have it automatically convert lambda expressions to expression trees.